# Unable to locate 3rd div element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, findelement

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]')
```

The above element is returned by the selenium chrome driver but the below element (div with main-content-row class) is not.

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]')
```

[image]

Comment: This question is missing basic debugging details.

Comment: What are some things i can do to debug this? Both the elements are within the same parent tag as seen in the pic. So i guess it would be in the same iframe as well. Not sure what else can be done here to debug it.

Comment: You wrote you can not find 3rd element. In order to help you we need to see that page with our browser. Don't you think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try providing the relative xpath,

```
driver.find_elements(By.className,'main-content-row')
```

or

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='main-content-column']/div[3]")
```

Note: The XPaths can be incorrect because the given information are not enough to provide the exact relative XPath. Please do the modifications you need if it is not working.

Comment: This worked thanks. used find element by class instead of by xpath